# does a primary key physically reorder on UPDATE?

Tags: mysql, sql-update, primary-key

John [showed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14175726/1382306) me that a primary key will physically order based upon the index, but will it *reorder*?

If I `UPDATE` the PK which takes one value in the column and makes it now greater when it was previously lesser another value, will MySQL physically reorder those rows?  Will the original value move "higher" physically than the other value?

I know about the pitfalls of `UPDATE`ing PK, but if anyone else knows of any limitations or restrictions, please feel free to add for +1s

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use InnoDB the engine uses clustered index when you define primary key. Then `clustered index` is mean that data stored by order of index because leaf level of index is data itself. 
When you `UPDATE` PK you change physical location of data.

Comment: You're sure of this?  Do you have link just in case?  I can't find this anywhere.  +1 after vox populi.

Comment: Here is links :) https://www.google.am/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&ie=UTF-8#hl=en&tbo=d&spell=1&q=mysql+clustered+index&sa=X&ei=s43oUK-mIOyP4gS9_YHACg&ved=0CCkQvwUoAA&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=a256d4f28226d313&bpcl=40096503&biw=1280&bih=675&ion=1